# I am new to react native and I am trying to send a username and password using an axios post request to web service

Tags: reactjs, native

I am trying to send a username and password  using an axios post request to web service but it gives me 
some error ocurred {data: "↵↵", status: 200, status Text: undefined, headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}

my code is

handleClick(){

```
          var payload = {
              "userame": this.state.username,
              "password": this.state.password
          }
          //axios.post('php/send_email.php', 'name=niall')
          axios.post('http://mywebserver/services/login.php', 'payload')
              .then(function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
                  if (response.data.code == 200) {
                      console.log("registration successfull");
                  }
                  else {
                      console.log("some error ocurred", response);
                  }
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                  console.log(error);
              });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes for 'payload' in the post request.

```
var payload = {
          "userame": this.state.username,
          "password": this.state.password
      }
      //axios.post('php/send_email.php', 'name=niall')
      axios.post('http://mywebserver/services/login.php', payload)
          .then(function(response) {
              console.log(response);
```